# grep a var name with consecutive numbers as a suffix

Tags: r, regex, data-manipulation

I want the index of some variables in a data-frame, but my `grep()` skill are insufficient.

Say I have this data frame,

```
( dfn <- data.frame(
a1   = c(3,  3, 0,  3, 0,   0),
a2   = c(1, NA, 0, NA, 1,   4),
a11  = c(0,  3, NA, 1, 3,   1),
a12  = c(0,  3, NA, 1, 3,   3),
a_12 = c(0,  3, NA, 1, NA, NA),
a_1  = c(12, 3, NA, 1, 4,  NA)) )
  a1 a2 a11 a12 a_12 a_1
1  3  1   0   0    0  12
2  3 NA   3   3    3   3
3  0  0  NA  NA   NA  NA
4  3 NA   1   1    1   1
5  0  1   3   3   NA   4
6  0  4   1   3   NA  NA
```

Now, what I want is to *grep* a1, a2, a11, and a12 (in real life the # after the `a`' is a consecutive list from 1 to 12), how do I do that? I've tried the two *grep's* below, but with no luck.

```
foo <- grep('a[1:12]$', names(dfn) )
names(dfn[,foo])
[1] "a1" "a2"
```

I've also tried this,

```
bar <- grep('a[c(1:12)]$', names(dfn) )
names(dfn[,bar])
[1] "a1" "a2"
```

What I want is

```
[1] "a1" "a2" "a11" "a12"
```

Secondly, can anyone direct me to a good `grep()` tutorial? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `grep('a[1:12]+', names(dfn))`

actually the proper way to do it would be `grep('a[1-9]+', names(dfn))` the + after the [1-9] means that values from 1-9 can be repeated any number of times after the a but must appear at least once.

Comment: You answered my question, but I ended up using @thelatemail's answer as I realized that my data had some variables `a1_a`, `a2_b` `…` `a12_l` that I also need to sort out. I tried adding a `$` after the `+` in your code, but couldn't solve it that way. regardless, I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @EricFail you MUST/should check the correct answer to the exact question...since questions and answers will be used by others after..of course with my respects to all the persons here how tried to answer.

Comment: @agstudy, I've marked CAPSLOCK's answer as the correct one as it solved the problem specified in the question (and added a note about why I used thelatemail's solution on my real data).

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this instead:

```
names(dfn)[names(dfn) %in% paste0("a",1:12)]
[1] "a1"  "a2"  "a11" "a12"
```

If you want the indexes, this will give you that:

```
which(names(dfn) %in% paste0("a",1:12))
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: I appreciate your elaborate answer, but I am curious to know if there is any advantages to the answer already provided by @CAPSLOCK?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am looking for the index positions and not the names.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. Don't you like/use `paste0()`? If so I am curious to learn why.

Comment: @EricFail - I am using a portable version of R on a memory stick that is at version 2.14, `paste0` doesn't exist when I am checking code. I've got nothing against it.

Comment: ah I was thinking of posting this answer too! but I wasn't sure if 12 was an actual upper bound or just used for example =P

Answer (score 1):

```
regmatches(names(dfn),regexpr('a[1-9]{1,2}',names(dfn)))
[1] "a1"  "a2"  "a11" "a12"
```

my regular expression is : a follwed by min =1 and max =2 numbers in the set [1-9]